# PHP get whole string not individual params in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

If I have a domain e.g. www.example.com/w/

I want to be able to get the whole string of text appended after the URL, I know how to get parameters in format ?key=value, that's not what I'm looking for.

but I would like to get everything after the /w/ prefix, the whole string altogether so if someone appended after the above

www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html

I would be able to get https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html

I was thinking of installing codeigniter on my server if that helps, but at the moment I'm just using core php

Comment: `str_replace('www.example.com/w/', '', $url);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `str_replace()`

```
$str = "www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html";
$str2 =  str_replace('www.example.com/w/', '', $str);
echo $str2;
```

**Output**

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html
```

Read more about [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with `strpos` and `substr`

```
$str = "www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html";
echo $str.'<pre>';
$start =  strpos($str, '/w/');
echo substr($str, $start + 3);die;
```

Output:

```
www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html

https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html
```

> strpos() will give you first occurrence of `/w/` and from there you can do substr with `+3` to remove `/w/`

OR Try this, with `strstr` and `str_replace`

```
$str = "www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html";
echo $str.'<pre>';
$str1 =  strstr($str, '/w/');
echo $str1.'<pre>';
$str2 = str_replace('/w/', '', $str1);
echo $str2.'<pre>';die;
```

Output:

```
www.example.com/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html

/w/https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html

https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/17/us/politics/trump-mueller-report.html
```

> strstr() will give you substring with given `/w/` and use str_replace() to remove `/w/`from new string